# Optimize SQL query: how to check if an Id is assigned to more than other Id (it should not)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a simple table like

```
client_id , company_id
100         1  
101         1  
102         1  
200         2  
200         2  
201         2
```

For each `client_id` I should have just one `company_id`. I need to make a query to check this.

What I was doing is:

```
        SELECT
    client_id,
    count(DISTINCT company_id) as count
        FROM table GROUP BY
    client_id
        HAVING count > 1;
```

If it's not empty, it should trigger an alert.

However, I was wondering if I could optimize it a little, because I don't really need to get every row, I just need to know if this query results in AT LEAST one row.

Is it possibe?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-explain.html The explain functionality is pretty straightforward to use and it'll give you a nice break down of what index is used, how many rows are scanned and things like that.

Answer (score 0):

`EXISTS` might be faster:

```
select distinct client_id
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.client_id = t.client_id and t2.company_id <> t.company_id
             );
```

I would expect a performance improvement under two conditions:

- There is an index on `(client_id, company_id)`.
- Most clients have only one company.